# Can Ace hear the voice of all things?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, is Ace able to hear the voice of all things?

I'm asking this question because Gol D. Roger was able to hear the voice of all things and ace is gol.d roger son.And he was able to hear the voice of all things like kokuki oden is showed in episode 969 when he and oden was annoyed

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit as to why you believe Ace could potentially hear the voice of all things because Gol D. Roger can?

Comment: AND Ace is gol.d roger son so :/